# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "dar caña"?

Tags: modismos, etimología, expresiones

Se usa con frecuencia la expresión "**dar caña**" para cualquiera de estos casos:

> [**dar caña**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7E5tpxx#4TAkbHA)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Provocar o recriminar a alguien.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Aumentar la velocidad o la intensidad de algo. *Da más caña al coche.*
> 3. loc. verb. coloq. *Esp.* Pegar, golpear, vapulear.

En general, yo estoy familiarizado con algo así como:

> *[En una carrera atlética]* Dale caña, que ya estás llegando.
>
> *[En un combate de boxeo]* Dale caña, que está casi KO.

La pregunta que me sobreviene es: ¿qué origen tiene esta expresión? Ninguna de las 19 acepciones que el DLE menciona para [**caña**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=V4kLM5TIbDXX2pDaIqEQ) tiene nada que ver, por lo que claramente es un modismo con algún tipo de historia que no encuentro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

El origen de esta expresión procede del movimiento de la caña (para incrementar la velocidad) que hay en las barcas en la parte posterior y se usa a modo de timón.

[image]

De modo que cuando das caña estás forzando algo para que vaya más deprisa:

> "Venga venga, que vas muy despacio. ¡Dale caña!"

En cuanto a la expresión:

> "Dale caña, que no tiene ni idea."

Nunca la he oído, o al menos en España no se utiliza.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Con "Dale caña, que no tiene ni idea" me refiere a la acepción "Pegar, golpear, vapulear."

Comment: Como nativo que soy, "Dale caña, que no tiene ni idea" me suena rarísimo, nunca he oído una expresión así. La frase original debía referirse a otra cosa.

Comment: Tal vez no di con un buen ejemplo. He editado mi pregunta para eliminarlo y sustituirlo por otro.

Comment: Ese si me cuadra :), viene del mismo origen. Aumentar la intensidad de algo, en este caso, golpeando.

Comment: Fíjate, y yo (que solo la uso para decir golpear) siempre pensaba que venía de pegar a alguien con una caña directamente (ya que incluso hoy en día es un castigo que se usa en algunas partes del mundo). Muy buena respuesta bienvenido/a a SE.Spanish

Comment: "Dale caña que no tiene ni idea" por ejemplo se lo diría al compañero jugando al mus o poker; en el contexto correcto, no me suena rara,

Comment: En algún momento pensé que "Dale caña" se interpretaba solo para referirse a "Beber cervezas".. Aclarado el tema. :)

Answer (score 0):

En Cuba, "dale caña" significa continuar una acción sin perjuicio alguno.
Ejemplo:

> —Amigo, no puedo esperar por ti.
>   —Ok, dale caña.  *[O bien: "vete sin problema"]*.