# ¿Cuál es el significado de la palabra «Estopa» referido al grupo musical con este nombre?

Tags: traducción, definiciones

Hay un grupo español que se llama «Estopa» y me gustaría saber qué significa esa palabra.

Comment: ¿Has intentado buscar un poco? Una búsqueda de dos segundos nos da con la entrada de Wikipedia donde lo explica muy claramente.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta, pero coincido con @fedorqui en que este tipo de preguntas se resuelven con una mínima búsqueda. Una pregunta interesante podría ser preguntar por el significado de la expresión "dar estopa", de dónde procede, su origen, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because can be solved with a very short web search and does not add value to the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de la Wikipedia, el diccionario de la RAE también es tu amigo:

> **[estopa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Gv051C2)**
>
> Del lat. stuppa.
>
> 1. f. Parte basta o gruesa del lino o del cáñamo, que queda en el rastrillo cuando se peina y rastrilla.
> 2. f. Parte basta que queda de la seda.
> 3. f. Tela gruesa que se teje y fabrica con la hilaza de la estopa.
> 4. f. Rebaba, pelo o filamento que aparece en algunas maderas al trabajarlas.
> 5. f. *Mar.* Jarcia vieja, deshilada y deshecha, que sirve para calafatear.
> 6. f. *C. Rica.* Fruto del paste lavado y sin semillas, que sirve de estropajo.
> 7. f. *C. Rica.* Residuo de la fruta cuando se le extrae el jugo.

Sin embargo, la acepción a la que se refiere el grupo no es ninguna de esas. En la jerga de España existe la expresión *dar estopa*. Tal y como dice en [la página del grupo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estopa_(banda)) en la Wikipedia:

> La historia dice que del grito *"¡Dadle estopa!"* que utilizaba el encargado de la fábrica [de una filial de Seat donde trabajaban] para que no cesaran en su trabajo, surgió el nombre [...].

Las expresiones *dar estopa* y *dar cera* son sinónimas de *dar caña*:

> **[dar caña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7E5tpxx)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Provocar o recriminar a alguien.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Aumentar la velocidad o la intensidad de algo. Da más caña al coche.
> 3. loc. verb. coloq. Esp. Pegar, golpear, vapulear.

Comment: _Las expresiones dar estopa y dar cera son sinónimas de dar caña_... que a su vez tiene [un origen](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14916/1674) la mar de curioso :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¡muy buena, no la conocía!

Answer (score 1):

En latín, stuppa, es un tipo de tela parecida a la arpillera. Esta tela está hecha con fibras de cáñamo, con lo que supongo que sacarían de ahí su nombre.