# Origen de "caña" para referirse a cerveza

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa

Entre las [caña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7E5tpxx) tenemos

> 7. f. Vaso, generalmente de forma cilíndrica o ligeramente cónica, alto y estrecho, que se usa para beber vino o cerveza.

Caña viene del latín *canna*, que creo que viene a significar "vara" o "bastón". De ahí supongo que vienen algunos de los significados relacionados con caña como "dar caña" (dale con el palo/vara). Sin embargo, cómo ha llegado a ser sinónimo de "cerveza" (o "vaso pequeño para cerveza")?

Entiendo que puede ser por la forma del vaso, que es "*cilíndrica o ligeramente cónica, alto y estrecho*", según el DLE, pero por esa regla de tres, tendríamos la mayoría de los vasos (las copas o chatos tienen otras formas características).

¿Puede alguien aclarar (o ampliar o corroborar) cómo "caña" ha llegado a significar "cerveza"?

Comment: Relacionado/mencionado: [¿De dónde viene la expresión “dar caña”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14915/5481). Yo estoy con guifa (ver comentarios a la respuesta de amchacon) en que "siempre pensaba que venía de pegar a alguien con una caña directamente"

Comment: Por lo que se ve las etimologías folklóricas sobre el asunto son múltiples, y ni una fuente razonablemente fehaciente…

Comment: @walen Es probable que, inicialmente, la palabra *caña* se usara para el vaso y haya acabado derivando en cómo se llena.

Comment: I always assumed it was an example of https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia which I was taught in English as container for the thing contained.

Comment: En [Caminando por Madrid] (http://caminandopormadrid.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/por-que-se-llama-cana.html)  opinan que 'el nombre de caña viene del tubo por el que sube la cerveza desde que sale del barril hasta que brota del grifo. Este tubo vertical o "caña" (palabra emparentada con caño y con cañería) es el que da nombre a la cerveza servida a través de un grifo'.

Comment: Para los que son de la opinión del origen de término en la forma del vaso solo decir que el vaso de tubo no es un requisito indispensable, la caña se sirve en vaso corto, largo o copa, y la cantidad varía según el recipiente que la contenga y el bar donde lo sirvan, pero en general, una caña suele ser de 20 cl.

Comment: En Chile una "caña" es un vaso de vino barato. Y por extensión "andar con la caña" es tener resaca.

Comment: Si han googleado un rato sobre este tema, se habrán dado cuenta de que antiguamente los objetos cilíndricos de vidrio se fabricaban soplando vidrio fundido por un tubo de fierro llamado "caña". Lamentablemente no pude llegar más allá.

Answer (score 6):

La mejor explicación de la etimología, sin relación con la cerveza (de esto me ocupo más abajo), que he podido encontrar es [la siguiente](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?can.a):

> La palabra *caña* viene del latín *canna*. De ahí
>   también las palabras *canal*, 
>   *canela* y *canuto*. La palabra
>   latina *canna* parece haber sido tomada del griego
>   κανών (*kanon*). El griego, a su vez, parece haberlo tomado del acadio,
>   de donde también viene قانون
>   (*qanun* = ley) en árabe y קנה (*qaneh* =
>   caña) en hebreo.
>
> ---
>
> La caña se refiere a un tallo de planta, como el bambú, que está hueco por dentro. De ese tallo se pueden fabricar vasos para
>   beber vino o cerveza. De ahí que en Chile, "**agarrar
>   caña**" quiere decir emborracharse y "**andar con la caña
>   mala**" es andar con resaca.

Y esto es una versión corregida procedente de la misma fuente:

> La palabra latina *canna* es un préstamo del griego, pero no de κανών, sino de
>   κάννα, que significa cálamo de escribir,
>   también estera, cerca o cesto de junco o caña. Se considera que en
>   todo caso κανών (caña o vara de medir) es un
>   probable derivado de κάννα. [Pierre] Chantraine afirma
>   que en efecto κάννα es un préstamo semítico,
>   relacionado con el acadio *qanu*, el ugarítico y el púnico
>   *qn*, y el hebreo *qanē*. Pero la forma semítica sería
>   a su vez un préstamo del sumerio *gin*.

Como puede verse, la web anterior recoge etimologías verosímiles; pero no es una autoridad ni aporta referencias, por lo hay que tomar esta información con cautela.

Vamos ahora a la pregunta en sí...

---

Y ahora vamos al meollo de la cuestión. Al menos donde yo vivo (norte de España), **solo** llamamos *caña* a la cerveza servida a presión, lo que en inglés denominan [*draught beer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_beer). Si aquí pides una *caña*, en ningún caso te servirán una cerveza de botellín en vaso cilíndrico, con independencia de lo que diga el DRAE. Es más, aquí entendemos *caña* como la forma corta de *cerveza de caña*, una suerte de aféresis.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, el origen de *caña* referida a la cerveza sería la forma en que se sirve. Veamos una imagen:

[image]

He estado investigando un poco y hay múltiples diseños para servir cerveza a presión, pero todos tienen en común que la cerveza discurre desde un barril hasta el grifo a través de un *caño* o *cañería*. Estos *caños* se ven más claramente en diseños antiguos. Ten en cuenta que, para que la cerveza salga a presión, la tubería debe ser ancha al principio y estrecha al final:

[image]

En esta misma línea, por estas latitudes el vaso cilíndrico o ligeramente cónico se conoce como *vaso de caña*, lo que indica que su nombre viene de la cerveza a presión que típicamente se sirve en él, y no al revés.

Aparentemente el uso ha hecho que, más al sur, tanto la cerveza como el vaso se denominen *caña* a secas. Y este último ha dado lugar a que, por metonimia, también su contenido sea una *caña*. Esto no es una teoría infundada porque, [según Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_beer#Canned_and_bottled_%22draught%22), en inglés ha sucedido algo parecido.

En resumidas cuentas, mi respuesta se basa en no hacer demasiado caso al DRAE, pero considero que en este caso concreto es lo más sensato, aunque no sea una buena idea en general. Además, hay que tener en cuenta que la RAE tiene su sede en Madrid e, inevitablemente está más influida por el español de esa zona que por el resto de la hispanidad.

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! Nótese que las referencias de [etimologia de chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/) solemos mirarlas con cierto recelo, pues tienden a listar todo tipo de teorías, sin mayor filtro.

Comment: Es cierto: salta a la vista que recogen opiniones contradictiorias de varios usuarios... Edito, pues.